# Integration of rational functions of the form $\frac{p(x)}{\left[q(x)\right]^\alpha}$ when $\deg p < \deg q$ and $q(x)$ cannot be factored

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

What is the general method to evaluate integrals of the form
$$\int\frac{p(x)}{\left[q(x)\right]^\alpha}\mathrm dx$$ when $\deg p < \deg q$ and $q(x)$ is irreducible?
I don't see how partial fraction decomposition can help here, since there is nothing to decompose.

For example, I'm having a hard time with
$$\int\frac1{\left(1+t^2\right)^2}\mathrm dt$$

For this one I also tried some substitutions, from which I was not able to conclude anything.

Comment: What about $\alpha$? Is it real?

Comment: @AlexSilva: Ah yes I forgot that. Yes, it's real, but case that interest me the most is that of $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For solving the integral
$$ \int \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}dt,$$ do the substitution

$ t =$ tan$(\theta) \Rightarrow dt = $sec$^2 (\theta) d\theta.$ Notice that cos$^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{tan}^2(\theta) }.$ Hence,

$$ \int \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}dt = \int \text{cos}^2(\theta)d\theta.$$

Comment: Ok, so for these integrals there is usually some trig substitutions!

Comment: For the general case, $\int \frac{p(x)}{q(x)^{\alpha}}dx$, I think there is no a closed form in general to solve it when deg$(q(x)) > 2$.